# Why MS doesn't have in its win32api a function that returns the font file name, given the font handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, fonts

This is the first time, in years of experience using the Windows API, that I confront a situation where I need to do something, that I can't, with Windows' current programming interface.

According to my research, the font "Arial Black" uses the file `arialblk.ttf` and **there's no file for the font "Arial Black Italic", neither for the font "Arial Black Bold"**, at least in my computer with a Windows 7.

I inserted below a program to show a few lines of text using the font "Arial Black", by itself, and then with italic and bold. To my surprise the italic text was rendered normally and the bold text was rendered as if it was just "Arial Black". Then I realized that the same thing happens with MS Word. I've also inserted a screenshot of a Word document, superimposed by the output from the code below. What's happening here ? Do I have to guess, which font file is being used in each case ? Apparently the Windows API does not give me the possibility of an answer. Why the mistery ?

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, UINT, LONG);


int APIENTRY WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclassx;

    wndclassx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndclassx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclassx.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wndclassx.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wndclassx.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wndclassx.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wndclassx.hIcon         = nullptr;
    wndclassx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclassx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wndclassx.lpszMenuName  = nullptr;
    wndclassx.lpszClassName = L"WndProc";
    wndclassx.hIconSm       = nullptr;

    if( !RegisterClassEx(&wndclassx) ) return 0;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WndProc", nullptr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    static HFONT s_hArialBlack, s_hArialBlackItalic, s_hArialBlackBold;

    switch ( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            LOGFONT lf;
            memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
            lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(20, 96, 72);
            wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, L"Arial Black");


            if( !(s_hArialBlack = CreateFontIndirect(&lf)) ) return -1;

            lf.lfItalic = true;

            if( !(s_hArialBlackItalic = CreateFontIndirect(&lf)) )
            {
                DeleteObject(s_hArialBlack);
                return -1;
            }

            lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
            lf.lfItalic = false;

            if( !(s_hArialBlackBold = CreateFontIndirect(&lf)) )
            {
                DeleteObject(s_hArialBlackItalic);
                DeleteObject(s_hArialBlack);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HFONT hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(ps.hdc, s_hArialBlack);
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 20, 10, L"Font Arial Black", 16);
            SelectObject(ps.hdc, s_hArialBlackItalic);
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 20, 50, L"Font Arial Black Italic", 23);
            SelectObject(ps.hdc, s_hArialBlackBold);
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 20, 90, L"Font Arial Black Bold", 21);
            SelectObject(ps.hdc, hFont);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(s_hArialBlackBold);
        DeleteObject(s_hArialBlackItalic);
        DeleteObject(s_hArialBlack);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the screen shot I referred to above :

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know the font file name, when you know what font you want?

Comment: I would not like to enter into this detail. But Windows has to do that. For instance, when a program calls GetFontData(), where the function first argument is a DC handle, Windows has to determine the font file name, based on the font selected into the DC. Why such a function doesn't exist in the Windows API ?

Comment: It's possible that the font renderer is simply skewing and thickening the font, rather than using a TTF definition. I'm especially suspicious of the italic version, but I'm not a font guy so I can't say for sure.

Comment: That's what I was told in another forum, i.e., that windows is using the font "Arial Black" to generate the slanted characters in this pseudo-font "Arial Black Italic". But that's not my major concern. I definitely think that a function that returns the file name given a font handle is mandatory in the WinAPI. I'd like to hear opinions on that. I may be wrong !

Comment: @crashmstr Suppose a program calls GetFontData() twice to obtain a copy of the font files containing the fonts "Arial Black" and "Arial Black Italic" in memory. Without knowing that the files are the same, the program would have to keep two copies of the same file in memory !!

Comment: I've run into this problem myself and was never able to find a solution that worked in all cases.  Good luck.

Comment: @user1162978: So what?  If the font is backed by separate font files, you'd need two items in memory anyway.  If they're the same file, it's not as space efficient as it could be, but it's the same as the worst, not-uncommon case.

Comment: Is it totally possible.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672527

Answer (score 4):

The function doesn't exist simply because there is no one-to-one mapping from logical fonts to physical fonts.  You already found that out partially by discovering the you don't have a dedicated set of outlines for italic.  Windows *synthesizes* missing styles by applying a transform on the outline.  That same synthesis didn't do anything special with the bold style, the font is already bold.

It gets much more convoluted when you display text that uses glyphs for which the font doesn't have an outline.  Like Chinese characters.  Then Windows completely *substitutes* another font that has the requested glyph.  Clearly that makes implementing the kind of function you want impossible.

Consider the Uniscribe api if you want better control over this process.

Comment: >> The function doesn't exist simply because there is no one-to-one mapping from logical fonts to physical fonts << But there is a many-to-one such a mapping, so this function is viable and helpful, as I explained with my example above, where you would have to keep two copies of the same font file in memory, without knowing that they represent the same file.

Comment: >> Consider the Uniscribe api if you want better control over this process << Suppose I want to process the font files myself, without using the Uniscribe libraries. How do I get certain that I won't have duplicate copies in memory of those files ??

Comment: Why do you assume there's duplication?  Surely there isn't.  You can't find out anyway so its fairly irrelevant.

Comment: Just by looking at the program output. Besides, what other font file could have been used in this case ? One other important aspect, is that every time Windows uses a font fallback substitution, MS Word shows the font that was used to print the character string, and not the font that was solicited. If you try the experiments with the "Arial Black Italic" and "Arial Black Bold" fonts in MS Word, you'll see that the font Arial Black doesn't change. As these two fonts don't exist in Windows 7, I'm forced to think that Windows used the same font file to print the 3 sentences in the Word document.

Comment: @user1162978: Why do you care so much about duplicate copies in memory?  You'd have the same memory usage if there were separate font files.  The fact that Windows is synthesizing a font behind your back without an actual file backing it is an implementation detail of the font that you shouldn't be concerned with.

Comment: >>You'd have the same memory usage if there were separate font files<< But if I knew that the "Arial Black Italic" uses the same file as the font "Arial Black", I would save one copy in memory. The pointer associated with the "Arial Black Italic" would point to the same block of memory associated with the "Arial Black" font. It is as simple as this ! Right now, I don't know that the fonts (or the files) are the same, so I have to keep two copies of the same file in memory.

Comment: @user1162978: But again: *so what*.  Suppose they eventually create a separate TrueType file for Arial Black Italic.  Now your memory usage would be the same as if you hadn't done anything, and you've wasted your time for no gain.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having two copies of the same file in memory unnecessarily. If you don't care about this, it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Not all fonts have designed italic or bold versions. Arial Black is one of those.

I don't think that most applications would need to be able to determine what actual font file is being used. Hence the lack of a direct API.

That said, there are some old samples that claim to do this. I have not tested either of the methods.

[Get the font filename (like tahoma.ttf)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d3ec5763-b7e8-4a29-9c50-1d6576ae6eae) with a c# example from 2006.
[Finding a Font file from a Font name](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1235/Finding-a-Font-file-from-a-Font-name) on CodeProject from 2001

Comment: Suppose a program calls GetFontData() twice to obtain a copy of the font files containing the fonts "Arial Black" and "Arial Black Italic" in memory. Without knowing that the files are the same, the program would have to keep two copies of the same file in memory !!

Comment: On the CodeProject link given above, you'll find this sentence "Unfortunately, this cannot be considered a 100% effective method for finding name of a font file"

Comment: Yes, I read that. The c# code might be more viable. Not working with fonts at this level, I don't know how much data is returned by `GetFontData`.