# Get a font filename based on the font handle (HFONT)

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I came across a situation where we needed to know the filename of a font currently in use by a [`QFont`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html). Knowing that a `QFont` can give us the font family and Windows `HFONT` handle.

The font family is not enough, because manipulating styles like `Bold` or `Italic` can result in Windows selecting a different font file. (f.e. arial.ttf, arialbd.ttf, arialbi.ttf, ariali.ttf).

This code sample should give us `<path>\arial.ttf`:

```
QFont font("Arial", 12);
FindFontFileName(font.handle());
```

while this code sample should give us `<path>\arialbi.ttf`

```
QFont font("Arial", 12);
font.setStyle(QFont::StyleItalic);
font.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
FindFontFileName(font.handle());
```

Comment: There are a surprising number of people who have wanted to do this: [Get a font filename based on Font Name and Style (Bold/Italic)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4577784); [Get a font filepath from name and style in C++/Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11387564). Weird, given I can't think of a situation where it would be required. Seems like bad design to me.

Comment: @CodyGray: in our application, users add their own fonts to a library. The user creates content using these fonts (they only select font family and apply some styles like you would in your favorite text editor). At the time the user deploys the content to a remote destination, the application must know which fonts to include in deployment.

Comment: @CodeGray: btw this isn't a duplicate because this is more a conversion from HFONT handle to filename then from family to filename.

Comment: Not sure that makes it not a duplicate. It's trivial to retrieve the font family when given an HFONT, just call `GetObject` to retrieve a `LOGFONT`. But don't interpret that as saying your advice is not useful or unwelcome—I upvoted both the question and answer as well.

Comment: But the opposite, getting a `HFONT` handle from a font-family is not so trivial. And that's what needed to be able to use the code in the answer. Anyway I've linked this Q/A in both questions you have pointed out.

Comment: This is something I want to do also. My reason is for solving customers' font installation issues for our font-intensive software application product. Although fonts normally reside in the official Windows Fonts folder, they don't have to. Font management products can move them around. Also some products that install fonts don't do things right. Finally, people mess with their registry. BTW, Mac OSX has an API to do the equivalent.

Comment: @CodeGray for embedding fonts in PDF files, for example, you need to know the name of the font file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows API [Font and Text Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144821(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't contain a function that returns the filename of a font. So a more creative solution has to be worked out.

The solution is to use the [`GetFontData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144885(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which will give us the exact copy of the original font file. The only thing that's left is comparing this data with the contents of all installed/known fonts.

**Lookup table**

We will first create a lookup table (`FontList`) of all installed/known fonts:

```
#define FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE    256
struct FontListItem
{
    std::string FileName;
    int FingerPrintOffset;
    char FingerPrint[FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE];
};

std::multimap< size_t, std::shared_ptr<FontListItem> > FontList;
```

The `FingerPrint` is a random part read from the font file in order to distinguish between fonts of the same filesize. You could also use a hash (f.e. SHA1) of the complete file to establish this.

**Adding fonts**

Method for adding a single font to this list is pretty straightforward:

```
void AddFontToList(const std::string& fontFileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fontFileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!file.is_open())
        return;

    size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
    if (fileSize < FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE)
        return;

    std::shared_ptr<FontListItem> fontListItem(new FontListItem());
    fontListItem->FileName = fontFileName;
    fontListItem->FingerPrintOffset = rand() % (fileSize - FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE);
    file.seekg(fontListItem->FingerPrintOffset);
    file.read(fontListItem->FingerPrint, FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE);
    FontList.insert(std::pair<size_t, std::shared_ptr<FontListItem> >(fileSize, fontListItem));
}
```

A Qt way to add all Windows fonts to the lookup table goes like this:

```
const QDir dir(QString(getenv("WINDIR")) + "\\fonts");
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
foreach (const QFileInfo fileInfo, dir.entryInfoList())
    AddFontToList(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath().toUtf8().constData());
```

File enumeration can also be done using [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API functions, but would be less readable for the purpose of this answer.

**GetFontData helper**

Then we create a wrapper function for the `GetFontData` function that creates a DC, selects the font by the `HFONT` handle and returns the fonts data:

```
bool GetFontData(const HFONT fontHandle, std::vector<char>& data)
{
    bool result = false;
    HDC hdc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    if (hdc != NULL)
    {
        ::SelectObject(hdc, fontHandle);
        const size_t size = ::GetFontData(hdc, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            char* buffer = new char[size];
            if (::GetFontData(hdc, 0, 0, buffer, size) == size)
            {
                data.resize(size);
                memcpy(&data[0], buffer, size);
                result = true;
            }
            delete[] buffer;
        }
        ::DeleteDC(hdc);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Font filename lookup**

Now we're all set for looking up the exact filename of a font by only knowing the `HFONT` handle:

```
std::string FindFontFileName(const HFONT fontHandle)
{
    std::vector<char> data;
    if (GetFontData(fontHandle, data))
    {
        for (auto i = FontList.lower_bound(data.size()); i != FontList.upper_bound(data.size()); ++i)
        {
            if (memcmp(&data[i->second->FingerPrintOffset], i->second->FingerPrint, FONT_FINGERPRINT_SIZE) == 0)
                return i->second->FileName;
        }
    }
    return std::string();
}
```

Comment: Note that not all fonts are stored in %WINDIR%\Fonts. Font paths are stored in a registry setting, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39093093/1836776 for more details, including why font names stored in that registry key are not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that doesn't required to use "hack" with the Windows Registry

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <list>
#include <windowsx.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dwrite.lib")

using namespace std;


list<WCHAR*> get_fonts_path(WCHAR* family_name, BOOL is_bold, BOOL is_italic, BYTE charset)
{
    list<WCHAR*> fonts_filename_list;
    HRESULT hr;

    IDWriteFactory* dwrite_factory;
    hr = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&dwrite_factory));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return fonts_filename_list;
    }

    IDWriteGdiInterop* gdi_interop;
    hr = dwrite_factory->GetGdiInterop(&gdi_interop);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        dwrite_factory->Release();
        return fonts_filename_list;
    }

    LOGFONT lf;
    memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(lf));
    wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, family_name);
    lf.lfWeight = is_bold ? FW_BOLD : FW_REGULAR; // TODO Change with the real ass weight
    lf.lfItalic = is_italic;
    lf.lfCharSet = charset;
    lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
    lf.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    lf.lfQuality = ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
    lf.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;

    HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HFONT hOldFont = SelectFont(hdc, hFont);

    IDWriteFontFace* font_face;
    hr = gdi_interop->CreateFontFaceFromHdc(hdc, &font_face);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        gdi_interop->Release();
        dwrite_factory->Release();
        return fonts_filename_list;
    }

    UINT file_count;
    hr = font_face->GetFiles(&file_count, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        font_face->Release();
        gdi_interop->Release();
        dwrite_factory->Release();
        return fonts_filename_list;
    }


    IDWriteFontFile** font_files = new IDWriteFontFile * [file_count];
    hr = font_face->GetFiles(&file_count, font_files);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        font_face->Release();
        gdi_interop->Release();
        dwrite_factory->Release();
        return fonts_filename_list;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++)
    {
        LPCVOID font_file_reference_key;
        UINT font_file_reference_key_size;
        hr = font_files[i]->GetReferenceKey(&font_file_reference_key, &font_file_reference_key_size);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            font_files[i]->Release();
            continue;
        }

        IDWriteFontFileLoader* loader;
        hr = font_files[i]->GetLoader(&loader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            font_files[i]->Release();
            continue;
        }

        IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader* local_loader;
        hr = loader->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader), (void**)&local_loader);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            loader->Release();
            font_files[i]->Release();
            continue;
        }

        UINT32 path_length;
        hr = local_loader->GetFilePathLengthFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, &path_length);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            local_loader->Release();
            loader->Release();
            font_files[i]->Release();
            continue;
        }


        WCHAR* path = new WCHAR[path_length + 1];
        hr = local_loader->GetFilePathFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, path, path_length + 1);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            local_loader->Release();
            loader->Release();
            font_files[i]->Release();
            continue;
        }

        fonts_filename_list.push_back(path);

        local_loader->Release();
        loader->Release();
        font_files[i]->Release();

    }

    font_face->Release();
    gdi_interop->Release();
    SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteObject(hFont);

    dwrite_factory->Release();

    return fonts_filename_list;
}


int main() {
    list<WCHAR*> fonts_filename_list = get_fonts_path(const_cast<WCHAR*>(L"alivia"), true, true, DEFAULT_CHARSET);


    // It will always be a lenght of 0 or 1
    for (WCHAR* font_filename : fonts_filename_list)
    {
        wcout << L"Font filename: " << font_filename << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```