# How does GDI function GetFontData know which font?

Tags: winapi, windows-store-apps, gdi

I have some old code that I want to port to metro. The old code uses the GDI function `GetFontData` to get font data from a table whose tag is being passed to it. I plan to replace it with `IDWriteFontFace::TryGetFontTable`.To do so I have to create a IDWriteFontFace object which requires path to the font file corresponding to the font it represents. But what I don't understand is where does `GetFontData` figure out the font files from whose tables it is supposed to fetch the data from? Does it do so from the device context that is passed to it?

Comment: Since you use ``GetFontData``, you probably select the font in the HDC. To get the right ``IDWriteFontFace``, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672527/15835974

Answer (score 2):

The font is the one currently selected in the Device Context. You can retrieve it by using [GetCurrentObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144869.aspx) with object type OBJ_FONT. You can then safely cast the returned HGDIOBJ to a HFONT.

As for retrieving the font file name, that's not easy. See [that SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769758/get-a-font-filename-based-on-the-font-handle-hfont)

Comment: Getting the font file name is not my requirement actually. But it looks like knowing it is the only way I can create the IDWriteFontFace object. Is there a way of creating this object without knowing the font file path/name?

Comment: @user Quoting http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/04/15/introducing-the-directwrite-font-system.aspx "Because a physical font encapsulates font data, you create an IDWriteFontFace object by specifying the source of the data: an IDWriteFontFile object."

Comment: I think I found a way to do this. Turns out there is a way to create the IDWriteFontFace object if you have the font object.Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371137(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There always some font selected in Device Context (I say always because there is  default font). So `GetFontData` returns that font depending on `HDC hdc` parameter.

As manuell mentioned `GetFontData` is similar to `(HFONT)(GetCurrentObject(hdc, OBJ_FONT))`

Comment: GetFontData is NOT "equivalent" to GetCurrentObjec, which just return a handle.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought that `GetFontData` works slightly different way.